# Static Table navigation in a Tabbar application

Tags: tableview, tabbar, navigationcontroller

I am working in an Tabbar based app.

On the last of 4 tabs(More), I have a ViewController with a StaticTableView in it, embedded in a NavigationController which is in a Relationship View with my Tabbar.

Problem is that when I navigate to a new scene from any of these rows in the StaticTableView and come back (I have in every new scene a back button to the tab), I can´t see the tabbar at the bottom of my table !

Why ? Any idea ?
[image: Tabbar with a TableView]
[image: first row was selected]
[image: back btn pressed]

Answer (score 0):

If you used storyboard you have to do this

http://imageshack.us/a/img805/2179/screenshot20130426at856.png

Sorry i can't post images!

Add:
Otherwise have to set the icon size 30x30 and 60 x60 so it does not look blurry. example home.png = 30x30 and home@2x.png = 60x60 for retina

Comment: Ready carefully ! 
" I have a ViewController with a StaticTableView in it, embedded in a NavigationController which is in a Relationship View with my Tabbar."
Exactly like in your screenshot ! 
What I´ve tried sucessfully was to use Push Segways instead of Modal ones. Then I don´t have the issue. But I wish to continue to use the Modal.